# How to allow a non-root user access a read-only filesystem?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, mount

I have an NTFS partition at `/dev/sdb1`.
When I mount it(`mount /dev/sdb1 mnt`), I can't access it as a non-root user, I get `permission denied`.
And I can't change ownership. From `chown username mnt` I get `chown: changing ownership of 'mnt': Read-only file system`, and still can't access the directory.

How to give permissions to a non-root user while retaining readonlyness?

Comment: Here's my fstab mount options for read only NTFS-3G access: `defaults,nofail,uid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0022,nls=utf8,ro`- change as needed. For RW access I add `noatime,discard`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm looking for a solution without fstab, something I could do when manually mounting

Answer (score 0):

Untested (I don't have any devices with NTFS), but should work:

```
ntfs-3g -o users,rw,umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```